# MakeParamSet function (ParamHelpers package): include formulas with parameters already defined

Tags: r

I am building parameter sets from `makeParamSet` and `generateDesign`functions (`ParamHelpers` package) in R. How can I include a formula using parameters that are already defined in the `makeParamSet` function ? Here is an example where I would like that `g` is the product of `a` and `c`:

```
ps <- makeParamSet(makeIntegerParam("a", lower=800, upper=7200),
                   makeIntegerParam("c", lower=632, upper=5688),
                   makeIntegerParam("e", lower=5, upper=45),
                   makeIntegerParam("b", lower=0, upper=7200),
                   makeIntegerParam("d", lower=0, upper=5688), 
                   makeIntegerParam("f", lower=0, upper=45))
Y <- generateDesign(10, ps, trafo = T)
```

Here are my attempts:

```
ps <- makeParamSet(makeIntegerParam("a", lower=800, upper=7200),
                   makeIntegerParam("c", lower=632, upper=5688),
                   makeIntegerParam("e", lower=5, upper=45),
                   makeIntegerParam("b", lower=0, upper=7200),
                   makeIntegerParam("d", lower=0, upper=5688), 
                   makeIntegerParam("f", lower=0, upper=45),
                   makeIntegerParam("g", lower = 1, upper = 1, trafo = function(x,a,c) x*a*c))
Y <- generateDesign(10, ps, trafo = T)

ps <- makeParamSet(makeIntegerParam("a", lower=800, upper=7200),
                   makeIntegerParam("c", lower=632, upper=5688),
                   makeIntegerParam("e", lower=5, upper=45),
                   makeIntegerParam("b", lower=0, upper=7200),
                   makeIntegerParam("d", lower=0, upper=5688), 
                   makeIntegerParam("f", lower=0, upper=45),
                   makeIntegerParam("g", require = quote(a*c)))
Y <- generateDesign(10, ps, trafo = T)
```

**Edit**:

The `g` parameter should be defined in `makeParamSet` because my goal is to add forbidden region using `g` as follows:

```
ps <- makeParamSet(makeIntegerParam("a", lower=800, upper=7200), ## bT
                   makeIntegerParam("c", lower=632, upper=5688), ## kR
                   makeIntegerParam("e", lower=5, upper=45),
                   makeIntegerParam("b", lower=0, upper=7200),
                   makeIntegerParam("d", lower=0, upper=5688), 
                   makeIntegerParam("f", lower=0, upper=45),
                   makeIntegerParam("g", require = a*c),
                   makeIntegerParam("h", lower=0, upper= max(g), ## Depends on g
                   forbidden = quote(h > g)))
Y <- generateDesign(10, ps, trafo = T)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best solution to this problem, since you're using `generateDesign` to sample from the parameter space, would be to just add in the parameter after the fact instead of defining it in the initial parameter set:

```
ps <- makeParamSet(makeIntegerParam("a", lower=800, upper=7200),
                   makeIntegerParam("c", lower=632, upper=5688),
                   makeIntegerParam("e", lower=5, upper=45),
                   makeIntegerParam("b", lower=0, upper=7200),
                   makeIntegerParam("d", lower=0, upper=5688), 
                   makeIntegerParam("f", lower=0, upper=45))
Y <- generateDesign(10, ps)
Y$g <- Y$a*Y$c
```

This will only give you the values of `g` that would correspond to the sampled values of `a` and `c`:

```
> Y
      a    c  e    b    d  f        g
1  5994 2813 27 4389 3321 11 16861122
2  3758 5392 32 1009 3684  1 20263136
3  1197 2446 19 2736  116  8  2927862
4  2530 3753  8 1827 2279 34  9495090
5  1675  649 37 3811 1303 19  1087075
6  5335 4878 14 5321 4271 45 26024130
7  3306 3396 42 6261 4753 38 11227176
8  6563 1155 40  333 5662 15  7580265
9  4224 4298 23 7180 1134 23 18154752
10 4805 1755 11 3145 2006 29  8432775
```

If you want to cover all possible values of g, it seems like the best solution would be to just hard code the limits (i.e., lower(g) = lower(a)*lower(c) = 800*632, etc.), but if you really want to define it based on the other parameter definitions, I think you'd need to create the original parameter set first, and then call it to get the previous parameters:

```
ps2 <- makeParamSet(makeIntegerParam("a", lower=ps$pars$a$lower, upper=ps$pars$a$upper),
               makeIntegerParam("c", lower=ps$pars$a$lower, upper=ps$pars$a$upper),
               makeIntegerParam("e", lower=ps$pars$a$lower, upper=ps$pars$a$upper),
               makeIntegerParam("b", lower=ps$pars$a$lower, upper=ps$pars$a$upper),
               makeIntegerParam("d", lower=ps$pars$a$lower, upper=ps$pars$a$upper), 
               makeIntegerParam("f", lower=ps$pars$a$lower, upper=ps$pars$a$upper),
               makeIntegerParam("g", lower= ps$pars$a$lower*ps$pars$c$lower, upper=ps$pars$a$upper*ps$pars$c$upper))
Y2 <- generateDesign(10, ps2)
```

But these wouldn't directly correspond to the respective sampled `a*c`:

```
> Y2
  a    c    e    b    d    f        g
 1  2434 1740 1033 3497  939 3001  9866916
 2  1895 2749 4762 3340 5161 1000 36786092
 3  4505 2378 6415 7183 2454 7119   713409
 4  5140 1028 4400 5798 3633 2560 28261522
 5  6904 6635 1928 5168 6607 6551 16555299
 6  2876 3761 2369 1912 4422 5877 40896236
 7  3563 5822 3110 2141 5624 4800 20026607
 8  5855 5242 5762 4628 1453 4381 31900665
 9  1143 4384 6648 1002 2967 3920 23614328
 10 6301 6153 3766 6094 6390 1978  5320086
```

**Edit:**

Try something like this to set a bound on `h`:

```
ps <- makeParamSet(makeIntegerParam("a", lower=800, upper=7200),
                   makeIntegerParam("c", lower=632, upper=5688),
                   makeIntegerParam("e", lower=5, upper=45),
                   makeIntegerParam("b", lower=0, upper=7200),
                   makeIntegerParam("d", lower=0, upper=5688), 
                   makeIntegerParam("f", lower=0, upper=45),
                   makeIntegerParam("h", lower=0, upper=5688*7200), 
                   forbidden=expression(h >= a*c))
Y <- generateDesign(10, ps)
Y$g <- Y$a*Y$c

> Y
      a    c  e    b    d  f        h        g
2  5226 4721 16 5808 2114  7 12630546 24671946
3  3587 2518 35 4989  212 14  5104204  9032066
4  6536 4237 38 7074  896 28  2853768 27693032
10 7135 3950  7  369 3426 38 23501987 28183250
31 4768 5541 26  216 3960 24 19840182 26419488
5  1164 3658 16 1600  794 39  1998994  4257912
41 5047 4653 20 4340 3261 40  6628254 23483691
1  4900 2880 22 6847 2566 19  1945704 14112000
21 3664 3625 36 7027 3955 15  2772633 13282000
11 3389 4229 22  468  593 36  2334981 14332081
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I have added some details to explain why `g` must correspond to `a` and `c` in `makeParamSet`